# Polymer 2 paper-input data binding does not work

Tags: polymer, polymer-2.x

Data binding does not work for me with `paper-input` i.e. this code does not do any data binding:

```
<paper-input 
  always-float-label 
  label="Search nodes" 
  value="{{userSearchText}}">
</paper-input>
```

(I am not using this inside a form.)

The equivalent code using `iron-input` and `input` (thanks to [m4b](https://github.com/PolymerElements/paper-input/issues/36#issuecomment-104742858)) does the data binding correctly:

```
<paper-item>Search nodes:</paper-item>
<div>
  <iron-input bind-value="{{userSearchText}}">
    <input value="{{userSearchText::input}}">
  </iron-input>
</div>
```

I am not sure if my bower install is messed up in some way. Here are the versions I got under bower_components now:

```
paper-input: 2.2.3
iron-input: 1.0.11
```

Please let me know what additional details you need.

---

UPDATE: adding bower.json

```
{
  "name": "abc-view",
  "main": "index.html",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "dependencies": {
    "polymer": "Polymer/polymer#2.6.0",
    "highcharts": "6.0.6",
    "highcharts-chart": "avdaredevil/highcharts-chart#2.0.1",
    "iron-icons": "PolymerElements/iron-icons#2",
    "paper-icon-button": "PolymerElements/paper-icon-button#2",
    "iron-image": "PolymerElements/iron-image#^2",
    "iron-icon": "PolymerElements/iron-icon#2",
    "paper-item": "PolymerElements/paper-item#2",
    "iron-selector": "PolymerElements/iron-selector#2",
    "paper-checkbox": "PolymerElements/paper-checkbox#2",
    "vaadin-grid": "#3",
    "vaadin-date-picker": "#2",
    "vaadin-combo-box": "#3",
    "paper-button": "PolymerElements/paper-button#2",
    "paper-input": "#2",
    "paper-fab": "#2",
    "paper-card": "PolymerElements/paper-card#2",
    "paper-progress": "PolymerElements/paper-progress#2",
    "paper-dialog": "PolymerElements/paper-dialog#2",
    "paper-spinner": "^2.1.0",
    "iron-flex-layout": "PolymerElements/iron-flex-layout#2",
    "iron-form": "PolymerElements/iron-form#2",
    "paper-toast": "#2",
    "neon-animation": "PolymerElements/neon-animation#2",
    "paper-tooltip": "PolymerElements/paper-tooltip#2",
    "paper-listbox": "PolymerElements/paper-listbox#2",
    "iron-pages": "PolymerElements/iron-pages#2",
    "paper-menu-button": "#2",
    "company-env": "ssh://stash.acme.com/proj24474/company-env.git#1",
    "company-ajax": "ssh://stash.acme.com/proj24474/company-ajax.git#1",
    "paper-radio-group": "#2",
    "paper-radio-button": "#2",
    "paper-tags-input": "paper-tags-input#1",
    "paper-tabs": "PolymerElements/paper-tabs#2",
    "paper-dropdown-menu": "PolymerElements/paper-dropdown-menu#2",
    "iron-collapse": "#2",
    "web-animations-js": "#2",
    "vaadin-material-theme": "ssh://stash.acme.com/proj1011/vaadin-material-theme.git#^0.6.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "iron-demo-helpers": "PolymerElements/iron-demo-helpers#^2",
    "web-component-tester": "Polymer/web-component-tester#^6",
    "webcomponentsjs": "webcomponents/webcomponentsjs#^1"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "polymer": "2.6.0",
    "paper-icon-button": "2",
    "iron-flex-layout": "2",
    "iron-icon": "2",
    "webcomponentsjs": "^1",
    "paper-input": "2",
    "iron-a11y-keys-behavior": "1 - 2",
    "iron-a11y-announcer": "1 - 2",
    "vaadin-material-theme": "^0.6.0",
    "vaadin-combo-box": "3",
    "highcharts": "6.0.6",
    "iron-meta": "1 - 2",
    "vaadin-control-state-mixin": "^1.1.4",
    "vaadin-text-field": "^2.0.0",
    "vaadin-overlay": "^1.2.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: Seems to work fine in this [codepen](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/xJmpad).

Comment: Thx. Think the issue is with my bower install/dependencies. I am not sure how to fix it.

Comment: please post your bower file for further help.

Comment: @PascalL. - added bower.json. We use some internal components as you can see. Not sure if any conflicts could be coming from there.